# Ant XPath support

Tags: xml, xpath, ant

Is it possible in Ant to get the value of the attribute based on the value of another attribute?

I need the value of templateId.extension when templateId.root="2.16.840.1.113883.2.20.6.9". I am using the xmlproperty task but I have not figured out how to embed an XPath expression in my query.

extract from XML file

```
  <templateId extension="111" root="2.16.840.1.113883.2.20.6.9"/>
  <templateId extension="4" root="2.16.840.1.113883.2.20.6.11"/>
```

my ant snippet

```
    <xmlproperty file="input/${id}.xml" keeproot="false" collapseattributes="true"></xmlproperty>
    <echo>content template: ${templateId[/.root="2.16.840.1.113883.2.20.6.9"].extension}</echo>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ant's native `xmlproperty` task doesn't have full XPath support. If multiple elements with the same name exist in the same location, their attributes are each assigned to the same property, in comma-delimited lists. At that point, they can be difficult to work with.

If you need to do advanced XML parsing, there's a 3rd party library called XMLTask available here: http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask

Then you can do something like this:

```
<taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask">        
    <classpath location="lib/xmltask.jar"/>
</taskdef>

<target name="default">
    <xmltask source="test.xml">
        <copy path="/parent/templateId[@root='2.16.840.1.113883.2.20.6.9']/@extension" property="xmltask.property" />
    </xmltask>

    <echo message="templateId extension with root value '2.16.840.1.113883.2.20.6.9' = ${xmltask.property}" />
</target>
```